# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version') with Xamarin and VS2015

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play-services

When I try and build my Android project with Google Play Location Services, I get the error in the title. From what I can google the answer is to either A: erase all your packages and try again, which I have done, or B: Take the version.xml from `android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject` and add it to your project. Unfortunately something changed in between when those answers were written and now, because there is no `libproject` and I can't find a `version.xml` anywhere. Are there any other solutions to this I missed?